# Why is my drop down empty

Tags: plugins, block-editor

For a wordpress challenge I need to make a dropdown with all categories and I need to use apifetch
So I have this :

```
/**
 * Retrieves the translation of text.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-i18n/
 */
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

/**
 * React hook that is used to mark the block wrapper element.
 * It provides all the necessary props like the class name.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/#useblockprops
 */
import { useBlockProps, InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { PanelBody, SelectControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { addQueryArgs } from '@wordpress/url';

/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * Those files can contain any CSS code that gets applied to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './editor.scss';




/**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {Element} Element to render.
 */
export default function Edit() {

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  const [chosenCategory, setChosenCategory] = useState(0);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchCategories() {

      const queryParams = { _fields: ['name', 'id'] };

      try {

        const response = await apiFetch({ path: addQueryArgs('/wp/v2/categories', queryParams) });

        setCategories(response);
        console.log(categories); 

      } catch (error) {

        console.log(error);

      }

    }

    fetchCategories();

  }, []);
  

  return (
    <>
      <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody title={__('Settings', 'rw-filter-categories')}>
          <SelectControl
            label="Choose Category"
            value={chosenCategory}
            options={categories}
            onChange={(category) => setChosenCategory(category)}
          />
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>
      <p {...useBlockProps()}>
        {__(

          "test",
          'rw-filter-categories'
        )}
      </p>
    </>
  );

}
```

but I see now that the dropdown is still empty.
Can someone explain why that happens and how to solve this ?

I see that the api returns this :

```
Array [ {…} ]
​
0: Object { label: "Niet gecategoriseerd", value: 1 }
```

I do not see any errors in the console but I see that categories is a empty array